planState.map is not a function
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AddOns from "./helpers/AddOns.js";
import { variables } from './helpers/Variables.js';

function App() {

    const [selectThisPlanState, setSelectThisPlanState] = useState({});

    function changeID(new_id) {
        setSelectThisPlanState(new_id);
        alert(new_id);
    }
    
    const [planState, setPlanState] = useState([]);

    function plan(name, value) {
        setPlanState(prev => ({...prev, [name]: value}))        
    };

    const getComputerProtectionPlansFromDb = async (productId) => {
        
        var protectionPlan = "";        

        var URL = variables.API_URL_ADDONS + "/" + productId;
        const response = await fetch(URL);
        const AddOns = await response.json();
                
        AddOns.forEach(protectionPlan_from_db => {
            if (productId == protectionPlan_from_db.productId) {
                protectionPlan = protectionPlan + protectionPlan_from_db.add_On + ";";
            }
        });

        plan(["d"], protectionPlan);                      
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {

        getComputerProtectionPlansFromDb(1);

        plan(["x"], "yyy");

    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {planState["x"]} <br /> {/* print "yyy" */}
            </div>

            <div>
                {planState?.map((item, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>{item["d"]?.split(";").map(plan => (
                        <div key={plan}>
                            <input type="radio" value={plan} checked={selectThisPlanState === plan} onChange={() => changeID(plan)} />{plan}
                        </div>
                    ))}</div>
                ))}
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default App;

{planState?.map((item, index) => ("  gives "planState.map is not a function"

planState state variable starts as an array:
const [planState, setPlanState] = useState([]);

The planState.map() function exists because planState is an array.
However, in the plan() function, you end up converting planState into an object:
function plan(name, value) {
  setPlanState(prev => ({...prev, [name]: value}))        
};

Plain objects do not have a .map() method (unlike arrays), thus the undefined function error is thrown when you try to call planState.map().

Wongin, your explanation makes prefect sense. Thanks!
